# How to keep data in a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays

**AAA.m:**

```
- (void)keepCurrentArray:(id)object
{
     _currentTest=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [_currentTest addObject:@"one"];
    [_currentTest addObject:@"two"];
    [_currentTest addObject:object];
    NSLog(@"My Array is:%@",_currentTest);
}
```

Class BBB.m is passing objects to class AAA. 
Right now if i'm passing X to the above method so the array will be: `one,two,X` . Then i'll send it Y and the array will be `one,two,Y` instead of what i want to accomplish: `one,two,x,one,two,y`.
Is that because I'm alloc and init _currentTest every time? How can I solve it?

**Update:**
I had a few suggestions on how to solve this and none of them worked for me. I've created a new project with just the code in the answers and i'm still getting the same result when I try to add the second object i get: `one, two, test` instead of `one,two,test,one,two,test`

Comment: I downloaded and looked at your project, but nowhere is keepCurrentArray: being called, and no NSLog statements are being generated so I'm not sure how you are testing this....

Comment: Are you sure you looked at my zip file? `[kios keepCurrentArray:@"Test"];` is being called inside aViewController.m LINE: 114 .I redownloaded the zip file again to make sure. NSlog IS being generated. Maybe you didn't noticed that there's a breakpoing inside ViewController.m?

Comment: Okay, found it.  I would not have expected to click on an **empty** row in the table in order to do it.  :)  Updating my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_currentTest=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` in a method is never a good thing!!!

As per naming convention it seems to be a property to the AAA Class. So for property, the alloc+init should be either in `init` or `awakeFromNib`. So that if is initialized just once.

However in some situations init is called more than once then your previous values are lost and new set are added.

So what you can do is make another class and put this `_currentTest` Array there and make it static and use it here. I hope this will work fine. And make sure in the init method of that class it is initialized just once, as :

```
//**this is not compiled and checked may contains typo and errors**

@implementation Storage

static NSMutableArray *yourStaticArray;

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (!yourStaticArray) {
            yourStaticArray=[NSMutableArray new];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addYourStaticArray:(NSString *)val{
    [yourStaticArray addObject:val];
}


-(NSArray *)yourStaticArray {
    return yourStaticArray ;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's because that you're alloc and init-ing every time you run that method.  Instead, put `_currentTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in AAA.m's init method.

**AAA.m**

```
-(id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
        _currentTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}

- (void)keepCurrentArray:(id)object
{
    [_currentTest addObject:@"one"];
    [_currentTest addObject:@"two"];
    [_currentTest addObject:object];
    NSLog(@"My Array is:%@",_currentTest);
}
```

Comment: I changed my code to your edit but now I'm getting `My Array is:(null)` in the log. Nothing is added to the array.

Comment: Make sure your -init method is actually being called. If some other method (say, -initWithCoder:, or a different -init method) is being called instead, move the array initialization there. The point is, only make a new array once per object.

Comment: If AAA is allocated from a nib, use awakeFromNib

Comment: No, I'm using storyBoard. This is AAA.m: http://pastebin.com/teQA56V3   only one init method

Comment: @Catfish_Man You are right. There's a breakpoint inside the init method you created but the program never get there. How do I call init and from where?

Comment: @MikaStern Sorry, not an iOS developer, so I have no idea what a storyboard is.  Try what Catfish_man suggested and replace `-(id)init`  with `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder` as anything called from nibs are initialized with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are creating a new array every time that your method is called.  Basically, you need to see if it has already been created, and only create it if needed.  You can change your method to:

```
- (void)keepCurrentArray:(id)object
{
    if (!_currentTest) 
    {
        _currentTest=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    [_currentTest addObject:@"one"];
    [_currentTest addObject:@"two"];
    [_currentTest addObject:object];
    NSLog(@"My Array is:%@",_currentTest);
}
```

**EDIT:**
In addition to the above problem, you also have this code which needs to be corrected (comments removed):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewController *kios = [ViewController new];
    [kios keepCurrentArray:@"Test"];
}
```

This code **creates a new instance of `ViewController`** every time that you click on a row in the table.  Because you are creating a **new** instance instead of reusing the old one, you start with an empty array each time.  In order to keep adding to the same array, you need to keep using the same view controller.

In order to do this, you need to add a declared property to your .h file, similar to your `currentTest` declared property:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) ViewController *kios;
```

Then, change your action so that you only create a new view controller if needed (the first time) and then reuses it after that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!_kios)
    {
        _kios = [ViewController new];
    }

    [_kios keepCurrentArray:@"Test"];
}
```

Comment: That gives me the same result I get in the first post. When I'm debugging I can see it never skips `_currentSandwich=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

Comment: Ummm, are you sure that you recompiled and are running the new code?  There isn't anything wrong with this check... :-)

Comment: Do I need to do anything else besides changing the code and hit run? :) ... maybe the property is wrong? `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *currentTest;`

Comment: I have a method called `initWithTitle` in another class. Maybe it got something to do with it?

Comment: Does it make changes to `_currentTest`?

Comment: That's strange. I've restarted Xcode and now I can see that init() is called BUT again                                              `_currentSandwich = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` is never skipped          . That's the code I'm using: `-(id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
        _currentSandwich = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}`

Comment: Note that my method is **not** in init, and nothing should be in init which is related to `_currentTest` if you are using this method.

Comment: I know, I commented on the wrong place. I do however, got the same problem with your code like any other code offered to me here. `_currentTest` keeps getting allocated inside the if every single time and i've no idea why.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you how to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to have a property for that `_currentTest` if you want to be able to keep it around between method call.

Put this in your .h file
`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray * currentTest;`

And this in hour .m file

```
- (NSMutableArray *)currentTest
{
    if (!_currentTest)
        _currentTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:11];

    return _currentTest;
}

- (void)keepCurrentArray:(id)object
{
    [self.currentTest addObject:@"one"];
    [self.currentTest addObject:@"two"];
    [self.currentTest addObject:object];
    NSLog(@"My Array is:%@", self.currentTest);
}
```

---

I Just try the code you've put on drop box and it's working exactly as it is suppose to, the array keeps it's value and everything,
**BUT**

> Exactly as it is suppose to is not what you are trying to achieve

Your problem is not in AAA.m, your problem is in BBB.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewController *kios = [ViewController new];
    [kios keepCurrentArray:@"Test"];
    [kios keepCurrentArray:@"Test2"];

}
```

I took the liberty of adding the `@"test2"` to the code you've send. If you run it you will see that your array still exist when the second call is made.
The `REAL` problem here is that you are creating a `NEW` ViewController each time. A brand new one, it is normal that it is empty (clean), it's a new one.
If I buy a note pad monday and fill it up, I don't expect when I'm buying an other one on friday to be already fill with the stuff I've wrote on monday in the previous one.
But this is exactly that behaviour that you are expecting from your ViewController.

> You need to store your NSMutableArray in an other object that doesn't
>   get destroy and created over and over again.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TableViewController keepCurrentArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x715d280'

Comment: @MikaStern Are you calling it on an instance of the class where you have define that method, from the look of the exception it look like you've messed up a call.

Comment: Since he isn't declaring _currentTest within the method, it already has to be a property (and in fact, he says so in the comment on my answer).

Comment: @Inafziger, then maybe the question should be updated to state all relevant variable

Comment: @VinceBurn I don't know what was the error earlier but now I've copied your code one by one and I'm still getting one,two,object every time I'm passing something to this method. This is how i'm calling this method within BBB.m:  `TableViewController *kios = [TableViewController new];
    [kios keepCurrentArray:[self.bugs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

Comment: After a debugger run i can see that `_currerTest` returns to be `NSMutableArray * 0x00000000` after each call.

Comment: I've created  New project with minimum code to try your code and I'm still getting the same result. one,two,test will never change. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17838/blah.zip